# Appium sendKeys doesn't work for iPhone 6

Tags: ios, appium

I setup the Appium for UI iOS testing. But I failed to get the sendKeys work at all. My testing environment:

1. OSX 10.10.2
2. Appium 1.3.6
3. Xcode 6.2
4. iPhone 6 (8.1) simulator, the softkey is default to be shown

[image]

I tried to "Send Keys" in Appium. But nothing happened. The log in Appium shows no error at all.

Here is the script: (Objective-C)

```
[[wd findElementBy:[SEBy xPath:@"//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIATextField[1]/UIATextField[1]"]] sendKeys:@"username"];
```

Here is the log file: (Any idea? Thanks.)

```
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/5e8073d7-8fa3-4bc1-8cfe-51f3b4d69111/element {"using":"name"}

info: [debug] Missing params for request: ["selector"] info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/5e8073d7-8fa3-4bc1-8cfe-51f3b4d69111/element 400 0.761 ms - 32 

info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/5e8073d7-8fa3-4bc1-8cfe-51f3b4d69111/source {} info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.mainApp().getTreeForXML()" info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.mainApp().getTreeForXML()

info: [debug] Socket data received (8192 bytes)

info: [debug] Socket data received (3184 bytes) info: [debug] Socket data being routed. info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":{"UIAApplication":{"@":{"name":"TestDemo","label":"TestDemo","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0","x":0,"y":20,"width":375,"height":647},">":[{"UIAWindow":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<AppiumAUT>\n    <UIAApplication name=\"TestDemo\" label=\"TestDemo\" value=\"\" dom=\"\" enabled=\"true\" valid=\"true\" visible=\"true\" hint=\"\" path=\"/0\" x=\"0\" y=\"20\" width=\"375\" height=\"647\">\n        <UIAWindow name=\"\" label=\"\" value=\"\" dom=\"\" enabled=\"true\" valid=\"true\" visible=\"true\" hint=\"\" path=\"/0/0\" x=\"0\" y=\"0\" width=\"375\" height=\"667\">\n            <UIAStaticText name=\"Login\" label=\"Login\" value=\"Login\" dom=\"\" enabled=\"true\" valid=\"true\" visible=\"true\" hint=\"\" path=\"/0/0/0\" x=\"156.5\" y=\"108\" width=\"62\" height=\"29\">\n    </UIAStaticText>\n            <UIATextField name=\"\" label=\"\" value=\"User name\" dom=\"\" enabled=\"true\" valid=\"true\" visible=\"true\" hint=\"\" path=\"/0/0/1\" x=\"107.5\" y=\"174\" width=\"161\" height=\"30\">\n                <UIATextField name=\"\" label=\"\" value=\"User name\" dom=\"\" enabled=\"true\" valid=\"true\" visible=\"true\" hint=\"\" path=\"/0/0/1/0\" x=\"107.5\" y=\"174\" width=\"161\" height=\"30\">\n                </UIATextField>\n            </UIATextField...","sessionId":"5e8073d7-8fa3-4bc1-8cfe-51f3b4d69111"}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/5e8073d7-8fa3-4bc1-8cfe-51f3b4d69111/source 200
229.958 ms - 13364 {"status":0,"value":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<AppiumAUT>\n    <UIAApplication name=\"TestDemo\" label=\"TestDemo\" value=\"\" dom=\"\" enabled=\"true\" valid=\"true\" visible=\"true\" hint=\"\" path=\"/0\" x=\"0\" y=\"20\" width=\"375\" height=\"647\">\n        <UIAWindow name=\"\" label=\"\" value=\"\" dom=\"\" enabled=\"true\" valid=\"true\" visible=\"true\" hint=\"\" path=\"/0/0\" x=\"0\" y=\"0\" width=\"375\" height=\"667\">\n            <UIAStaticText name=\"Login\" label=\"Login\" value=\"Login\" dom=\"\" enabled=\"true\" valid=\"true\" visible=\"true\" hint=\"\" path=\"/0/0/0\" x=\"156.5\" y=\"108\" width=\"62\" height=\"29\">\n    </UIAStaticText>\n            <UIATextField name=\"\" label=\"\" value=\"User name\" dom=\"\" enabled=\"true\" valid=\"true\" visible=\"true\" hint=\"\" path=\"/0/0/1\" x=\"107.5\" y=\"174\" width=\"161\" height=\"30\">\n                <UIATextField name=\"\" label=\"\" value=\"User name\" dom=\"\" enabled=\"true\" valid=\"true\" visible=\"true\" hint=\"\" path=\"/0/0/1/0\" x=\"107.5\" y=\"174\" width=\"161\" height=\"30\">\n                </UIATextField>\n            </UIATextField...","sessionId":"5e8073d7-8fa3-4bc1-8cfe-51f3b4d69111"}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/5e8073d7-8fa3-4bc1-8cfe-51f3b4d69111/orientation {} info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.getScreenOrientation()" info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.getScreenOrientation()

info: [debug] Socket data received (33 bytes)

info: [debug] Socket data being routed. info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":"PORTRAIT"} info: [debug] Setting internal orientation to PORTRAIT info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":"PORTRAIT","sessionId":"5e8073d7-8fa3-4bc1-8cfe-51f3b4d69111"}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/5e8073d7-8fa3-4bc1-8cfe-51f3b4d69111/orientation 200
117.559 ms - 82 {"status":0,"value":"PORTRAIT","sessionId":"5e8073d7-8fa3-4bc1-8cfe-51f3b4d69111"} info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/5e8073d7-8fa3-4bc1-8cfe-51f3b4d69111/screenshot {} info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.getScreenOrientation()" info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.getScreenOrientation()

info: [debug] Socket data received (33 bytes)

info: [debug] Socket data being routed. info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":"PORTRAIT"} info: [debug] Setting internal orientation to PORTRAIT info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.capture('screenshot10e27e81-2e0c-4cb4-851d-d5fad89ba503')" info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.capture('screenshot10e27e81-2e0c-4cb4-851d-d5fad89ba503')

info: [debug] Socket data received (25 bytes)

info: [debug] Socket data being routed. info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":""} info: [debug] Waiting 10000 ms for screenshot to ge generated.

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-24 07:59:21 +0000 Debug: Got new command 47 from instruments: au.mainApp().getTreeForXML()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-24 07:59:21 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.mainApp().getTreeForXML()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-24 07:59:21 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-24 07:59:21 +0000 Debug: responding with:valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0","x":0,"y":0,"width":375,"height":667},">":[{"UIAStaticText":{"@":{"name":"Login","label":"Login","value":"Login","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/0","x":156.5,"y":108,"width":62,"height":29},">":[]}},{"UIATextField":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":"User name","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/1","x":107.5,"y":174,"width":161,"height":30},">":[{"UIATextField":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":"User name","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/1/0","x":107.5,"y":174,"width":161,"height":30},">":[]}}]}},{"UIAStaticText":{"@":{"name":"Label","label":"Label","value":"Label","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/2","x":117.5,"y":184,"width":42,"height":20.5},">":[]}},{"UIASecureTextField":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":"Password","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/3","x":107.5,"y":227.5,"width":161,"height":30},">":[{"UIASecureTextField":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":"Password","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/3/0","x":107.5,"y":227.5,"width":161,"height":30},">":[]}}]}},{"UIAButton":{"@":{"name":"Login","label":"Login","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/4","x":130.5,"y":290,"width":114,"height":30},">":[]}}]}},{"UIAWindow":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1","x":0,"y":0,"width":375,"height":667},">":[{"UIAKeyboard":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0","x":0,"y":409,"width":375,"height":258},">":[{"UIAImage":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/0","x":0,"y":409,"width":375,"height":42},">":[]}},{"UIAElement":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/1","x":6,"y":407,"width":112,"height":42},">":[]}},{"UIAElement":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/2","x":131,"y":407,"width":113,"height":42},">":[]}},{"UIAElement":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/3","x":257,"y":407,"width":112,"height":42},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"q","label":"q","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/4","x":0,"y":460,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"w","label":"w","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/5","x":37.5,"y":460,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"e","label":"e","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/6","x":75,"y":460,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"r","label":"r","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/7","x":112.5,"y":460,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"t","label":"t","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/8","x":150,"y":460,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"y","label":"y","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/9","x":187.5,"y":460,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"u","label":"u","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/10","x":225,"y":460,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"i","label":"i","val ue":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/11","x":262.5,"y":460,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"o","label":"o","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/12","x":300,"y":460,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"p","label":"p","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/13","x":337.5,"y":460,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"a","label":"a","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/14","x":18.5,"y":514,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"s","label":"s","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/15","x":56,"y":514,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"d","label":"d","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/16","x":93.5,"y":514,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"f","label":"f","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/17","x":131,"y":514,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"g","label":"g","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/18","x":169,"y":514,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"h","label":"h","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/19","x":206.5,"y":514,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"j","label":"j","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/20","x":244,"y":514,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"k","label":"k","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/21","x":281.5,"y":514,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"l","label":"l","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/22","x":319,"y":514,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAButton":{"@":{"name":"shift","label":"shift","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":"Triple-tap to enter caps lock","path":"/0/1/0/23","x":0,"y":568,"width":48,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"z","label":"z","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/24","x":56,"y":568,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"x","label":"x","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/25","x":93.5,"y":568,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"c","label":"c","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/26","x":131,"y":568,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"v","label":"v","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/27","x":169,"y":568,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"b","label":"b","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/28","x":206.5,"y":568,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"n","label":"n","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/29","x":244,"y":568,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"m","label":"m","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/30","x":281.5,"y":568,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"Delete","label":"Delete","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/31","x":327,"y":568,"width":48,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"more, numbers","label":"more, numbers","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint" :null,"path":"/0/1/0/32","x":0,"y":6 info: [debug] [INST] 20,"width":46.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAButton":{"@":{"name":"Next keyboard","label":"Next keyboard","value":"Emoji","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":"Double-tap and hold, then drag up to select another keyboard","path":"/0/1/0/33","x":46.5,"y":620,"width":47,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAKey":{"@":{"name":"space","label":"space","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/34","x":93,"y":620,"width":188.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAButton":{"@":{"name":"Dictate","label":"Dictate","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":"Double tap to start dictation.  Two finger double tap when finished","path":"/0/1/0/35","x":93.5,"y":620,"width":37.5,"height":46},">":[]}},{"UIAButton":{"@":{"name":"Return","label":"return","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0/36","x":281.5,"y":620,"width":93.5,"height":46},">":[]}}]}}]}},{"UIAWindow":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/2","x":0,"y":0,"width":375,"height":667},">":[{"UIAStatusBar":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/2/0","x":0,"y":0,"width":375,"height":20},">":[{"UIAElement":{"@":{"name":"Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top","label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":"Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top","path":"/0/2/0/0","x":6,"y":0,"width":38,"height":20},">":[]}},{"UIAElement":{"@":{"name":"3 of 3 Wi-Fi bars","label":"3 of 3 Wi-Fi bars","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":"Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top","path":"/0/2/0/1","x":49,"y":0,"width":13,"height":20},">":[]}},{"UIAElement":{"@":{"name":"3:59 PM","label":"3:59 PM","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":"Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top","path":"/0/2/0/2","x":164,"y":0,"width":47,"height":20},">":[]}},{"UIAElement":{"@":{"name":"100% battery power","label":"100% battery power","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":"Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top","path":"/0/2/0/3","x":345,"y":0,"width":25,"height":20},">":[]}}]}}]}}]}}} info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-24 07:59:21 +0000 Debug: Running system command #48: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":{"UIAApplication":{"@":{"name":"TestDemo","label":"TestDemo","value":null,"dom"... info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-24 07:59:21 +0000 Debug: Got new command 48 from instruments: au.getScreenOrientation()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-24 07:59:21 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.getScreenOrientation() info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-24 07:59:21
+0000 Debug: evaluation finished

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-24 07:59:21 +0000 Debug: responding with: info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-24 07:59:21 +0000 Debug: Running system command #49: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":"PORTRAIT"}...

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-24 07:59:21 +0000 Debug: Got new command 49 from instruments: au.getScreenOrientation() info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-24 07:59:21 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.getScreenOrientation()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-24 07:59:21 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-24 07:59:21 +0000 Debug: responding with: info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-24 07:59:21 +0000 Debug: Running system command #50: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":"PORTRAIT"}...

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-24 07:59:21 +0000 Debug: Got new command 50 from instruments: au.capture('screenshot10e27e81-2e0c-4cb4-851d-d5fad89ba503')

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-24 07:59:21 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.capture('screenshot10e27e81-2e0c-4cb4-851d-d5fad89ba503') info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-24 07:59:21 +0000 Debug: target.captureRectOnScreenWithName("{origin:{x:0.00,y:0.00}, size:{height:667.00,width:375.00}}", UIScreen, "screenshot10e27e81-2e0c-4cb4-851d-d5fad89ba503")

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-24 07:59:21 +0000 Screenshot captured.

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-24 07:59:21 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-24 07:59:21 +0000 Debug: responding with:

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-24 07:59:21 +0000 Debug: Running system command #51: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":""}...

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":"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...","sessionId":"5e8073d7-8fa3-4bc1-8cfe-51f3b4d69111"}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/5e8073d7-8fa3-4bc1-8cfe-51f3b4d69111/screenshot 200
884.141 ms - 97822 {"status":0,"value":"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...","sessionId":"5e8073d7-8fa3-4bc1-8cfe-51f3b4d69111"}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/5e8073d7-8fa3-4bc1-8cfe-51f3b4d69111/contexts {} info: [debug] [REMOTE] Debugger socket connected to ::1:27753 info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending connection key info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending
_rpc_reportIdentifier: message to remote debugger info: [debug] [REMOTE] {"__argument":{"WIRConnectionIdentifierKey":"c81f2b85-5108-449d-a70b-95aab0877f21"},"__selector":"_rpc_reportIdentifier:"}

info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger

info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger info: [debug] [REMOTE] {"__argument":{"WIRSimulatorBuildKey":"12B411","WIRSimulatorProductVersionKey":"8.1","WIRSimulatorNameKey":"iPhone Simulator"},"__selector":"_rpc_reportSetup:"} info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sim name: iPhone Simulator info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sim build: 12B411 info: [debug] [REMOTE] {"__argument":{"WIRApplicationDictionaryKey":{}},"__selector":"_rpc_reportConnectedApplicationList:"} warn: Remote debugger did not list com.wowtv.TestDemo among its available apps info: [debug] [REMOTE] Disconnecting from remote debugger info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":["NATIVE_APP"],"sessionId":"5e8073d7-8fa3-4bc1-8cfe-51f3b4d69111"}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/5e8073d7-8fa3-4bc1-8cfe-51f3b4d69111/contexts 200
80.879 ms - 86 {"status":0,"value":["NATIVE_APP"],"sessionId":"5e8073d7-8fa3-4bc1-8cfe-51f3b4d69111"} info: [debug] [REMOTE] Debugger socket disconnected
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have disable the option to Connect Hardware Keyboard on your simulator keyboard setting. Hardware>Keyboard